# XSL apply template when node is missing

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I'm having trouble applying templates when the node I want to format is missing.  I don't believe that explanation is very descriptive so I've included a mocked up example to show exactly what I mean.  I have XML of the following form:

```
<mains>
    <main>
        <detail1>stuff11</detail1>
        <detail2>stuff12</detail2>
    </main>
    <main>
        <detail1>stuff22</detail1>
    </main>
    <main>
        <detail2>stuff32</detail2>
        <detail3>stuff33</detail3>
    </main>
</mains>
```

Currently, I use an XSL that does the following

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/mains">
<table>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="main"/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="main">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail1"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail2"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="detail3"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="detail1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="detail2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="detail3">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I apply the XSL I get the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <tr><td>stuff11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff12</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff21</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff32</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff33</td></tr>
</table>
```

Which isn't quite the table that I wanted.  I instead want the following table

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<table>
    <tr><td>stuff11</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff12</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff21</td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff32</td></tr>
    <tr><td>stuff33</td></tr>
</table>
```

For arguments sake, say that I cant move the `<tr><td></td></tr>` tags outside of the various details templates and they have to stay in there.

I know I could do `<xsl:if>` on each template call and check the value-of to make sure it exists or not, but that feels very clunky. Is there a setting to make `apply-templates` apply even when the node is missing?

Comment: Are you sure that is the result you want? Or did you perhaps mean a row for each main, with 3 cells in each row?

Comment: Yes I'm sure.  This is an example, it isn't rows and columns that I want, the templates I'm applying have more to them.  I just want to apply templates on nodes that are missing.  Or something that would get me that effect without being too clunky.  (best practice would be ideal)

Comment: "*I just want to apply templates on nodes that are missing.*" As you found out, that won't produce any result - so you will need to reconsider this statement: "*For arguments sake, say that I cant move the <tr><td></td></tr> tags outside of the various details templates and they have to stay in there.*". BTW, in my experience, a contrived example does not lead to good answers.

Comment: I believe you do understand the effect I want.  The templates I'm applying are complicated and don't have anything to do with the issue I'm facing.  In my experience, a simple question that gets to the root of the problem leads to a good answer, assuming the response isn't "Well why would you want to do that in the first place?"

Comment: The problem with your example is that it leads to established thought patterns ("Oh, he wants a table, I know how to produce a table"). Anyway, *something* in your requirements has to give, as it's not possible to satisfy both, IMHO.

Comment: I agree, I could have done a better job of making up a dummy example that doesn't lead to established thought patterns.  I should have done something like ... other code.. instead of going to <tr><td> tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a workaround.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=".">
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="detail1" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This will make it so that the template is always called and I can handle missing nodes with `xsl:choose` in the template instead of wrapping `xsl:choose` around every template call.

That being said, I'm not sure what is 'best practice' so if someone has a better solution I'm still interested in hearing it.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about a "node that doesn't exist" is wishful thinking. There is no such node, therefore you can't select it, therefore you can't process it. You need an xsl:choose.

Comment: That's kind of a curt response, but I voted it up because you actually addressed part of my question.  I thought there was possibly a setting to turn on this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but applying templates to the empty set does produce an empty result.

You may be able to get what you want by refactoring the HTML wrappers upward -- generate the `<tr><td></td></tr>` wrapping in the calling template, and have the "detail" templates only generate the data content.

Or, perhaps just have a single `<xsl:apply-templates select="detail1|detail2|detail3">`, but apply an `<xsl:sort>` to it to produce the results in the desired order (1's, then 2's, then 3's).

Comment: Appreciate the response but needed to keep stuff inside of templates so moving it out isn't an option. :-/